# Why is auto-increment pattern bad when scaling in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, scalability, auto-increment

I'm trying to understand why [auto-increment pattern is bad when scaling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

I've also read [this article](https://blog.serverdensity.com/switching-to-mongodb-and-auto-increment/). There are such words in it:

- Instead, you need to use a proper UUID method to ensure that you don’t hit race conditions and the ID is truly unique across clusters.

I'm trying to find out the exact scenario of circumstances with `_id` duplication in shards.

And another one question: what about auto-increment for **non-primary** key? Is it safe?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to guarantee that an auto-increment value is unique, the ID creation must occur on a single thread on a single host (even if multiple threads are used, the point of ID creation must block other threads). So, in a cluster of 100 servers, IDs must be created on 1 thread on 1 out the 100 servers. This not just a performance bottleneck, it is possible that the creation of 2 auto-increment IDs might block each other, which is the race condition noted in the quotation you've cited.

It should be noted that transactional RDBMS systems like Oracle and SQL Server have solved the race condition problem, but there is no solution to the performance bottleneck.

So: no, don't use auto-increment in non-primary keys if you anticipate the need to scale your system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Information about RDBMS is useful as well. There is only one thing that is unclear for me now: how can be the race condition when using `findAndModify` which is atomic AFAIK. Am I missing something? Can you please explain this?

Comment: In order to get a race condition, you'd have to be generating, directly or indirectly, one id while you were in the process of generated another ID. I don't see the race condition vulnerability in the code you're referencing. However, I would say that if generating a unique integer ID sequence is part of your requirements, Mongo is not the best implementation choice. Better to generate your ID sequence in an RDBMS that is set up for this purpose. You can then use the ID in Mongo once it's been generated. If scalability is not an issue, I'd say go ahead and use the Mongo findAndModify hack.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand what is what